# Excel macro sends email only to first email address, not all

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

I'm quite a novice at macros but I've created a macro in Excel that I am want to loop through my spreadsheet and send emails when a specific cell value is null. This code works to send the first email but all the remaining emails show only the first email recipient and subject.  It does not execute to send a unique second or any other emails.

What can I try next?

Below is the code I am using:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngMyDataSet As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim sTo As String
Dim MailBody As Range
Dim EmailRecipient As String
Dim Signature As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
Set Rng = .Range("AH5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
For Each rngCell In Rng
If rngCell.Offset(0, 6) > 0 Then

ElseIf rngCell.Offset(0, 5) > Evaluate("Today() +7") And _
rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value <= Evaluate("Today() +120") Then
rngCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Date

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "According to my records, your " & Range("A5").Value & " contract is due for review         " & rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value & _
".  It is important you review this contract ASAP and email me with any changes made.  If it is renewed, please fill out the Contract Cover Sheet which can be found in the Everyone folder and send me the cover sheet along with the new original contract."
EmailSendTo = Sheets("sheet1").Range("AH5").Value
EmailSubject = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A5").Value
Signature = "C:\Documents and Settings\" & Environ("rmm") & _
"\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures\rm.htm"
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = EmailSendTo
.CC = "hhh@gmail.com"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = EmailSubject
.Body = strbody
.Display
Send_Value = Mail_Recipient.Offset(i - 1).Value
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End If

Next rngCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `EmailSendTo = Sheets("sheet1").Range("AH5").Value` is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

> This code works to send the first email but all the remaining emails show only the first email recipient and subject.

Your code creates a new mail items based on the data in the Excel worksheet. But it doesn't send any email automatically. Instead, the code displays a newly created item. To send the mail item you need to call the `Send` method instead of `Display` as the following code shows:

```
With OutMail
.To = EmailSendTo
.CC = "hhh@gmail.com"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = EmailSubject
.Body = strbody
.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

Change rows when creating the mail.

Appears the range is bigger than you think it is. Replacing column AH with column A will probably suffice.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

' Starting in row 5
' Contract ID in column A
' Date in column F
' Zero or positive integer in column G
' Recipient in column AH

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim EmailSendTo As String
Dim EmailSubject As String

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    
    'Set Rng = .Range("AH5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    'Debug.Print "Rng.Cells.Count: " & Rng.Cells.Count
    ' To see Rng
    'Rng.Select
    
    ' Assumes the number of rows in column A is the same as in column AH
    Set Rng = .Range("A5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Debug.Print "Rng.Cells.Count: " & Rng.Cells.Count
    ' To see Rng
    'Rng.Select
End With

' Outside of the For loop
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each rngCell In Rng

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "rngCell.Row.........: " & rngCell.Row
    Debug.Print "       rngCell.Offset(0, 6): " & rngCell.Offset(0, 6)
    
    If rngCell.Offset(0, 6) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "       rngCell.Offset(0, 6) > 0 = Do nothing."
    
    Else
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "       rngCell.Offset(0, 5): " & rngCell.Offset(0, 5)
        Debug.Print "                  Today + 7: " & Evaluate("Today() +7")
        Debug.Print " CDbl(rngCell.Offset(0, 5)): " & CDbl(rngCell.Offset(0, 5))
        Debug.Print "                Today + 120: " & Evaluate("Today() +120")
        
        If rngCell.Offset(0, 5) > Evaluate("Today() +7") And _
          rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value <= Evaluate("Today() +120") Then
    
            Debug.Print "       rngCell.Offset(0, 5): " & rngCell.Offset(0, 5) & " = Action"
            
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
            Dim strbody As String
            strbody = "According to my records, your " & Range("A" & rngCell.Row).Value & " contract is due for review         " & rngCell.Offset(0, 5).Value & _
            ".  It is important you review this contract ASAP and email me with any changes made.  If it is renewed, please fill out the Contract Cover Sheet which can be found in the Everyone folder and send me the cover sheet along with the new original contract."
                       
            EmailSendTo = Sheets("sheet1").Range("AH" & rngCell.Row).Value
            EmailSubject = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & rngCell.Row).Value
            
            With OutMail
                .To = EmailSendTo
                .CC = "hhh@gmail.com"
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = EmailSubject
                .Body = strbody
                .Display
            End With
            
            Set OutMail = Nothing
                        
        Else
            Debug.Print
            Debug.Print "       rngCell.Offset(0, 5): " & rngCell.Offset(0, 5) & " = Do nothing."
            
        End If
        
    End If

Next rngCell

Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```

Always delete `On Error Resume Next` when followed by code for creating mailitems. It should be the correct action 99.99999% of the time.